# Inline CSS Not Working for added Widget

Tags: css, gwt

I can't seem to figure out why my added Widgets will not display inline. I would like my Validation Widget to display inline after the label. But no matter what I do it wont. Why?

```
<ui:UiBinder
 xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
  xmlns:validation='urn:import:com.versature.vsm.client.ui.validation'>

<ui:style>
.validationField {
    display:inline-block;
}
</ui:style>

<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mainPanel">
     <div class="{style.validationField}">
         <g:Label text="ACCOUNT NUM:"/> 
         <validation:ValidationField ui:field="accountNumberValidation"/>
     </div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like my Validation Widget to display inline after the label.
>   But no matter what I do it wont. Why?

You are currently making the *container* that holds them both `inline`.  To make the individual elements inline, you could either (be sure to only apply one of the following solutions; applying both will not work):

**(1) Set the *children* of your `validationField` CSS class to display inline, by changing your style to:**

```
<ui:style>
.validationField * {
    display:inline-block;
}
</ui:style>
```

**(2) Apply the `validationField` CSS class to your `ValidationField` GWT widget *only*, by changing your UiBinder XML to:**

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mainPanel">
     <g:Label text="ACCOUNT NUM:"/> 
     <validation:ValidationField ui:field="accountNumberValidation" stylePrimaryName="{style.validationField}"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for information but even making the elements inline leaves me in the same situation. The above code still has the validation field on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<g:Label>` with `<g:InlineLabel>`.

Label uses a `<div>`, which is by default displayed as a block, whereas InlineLabel uses a `<span>`.